# Expecting but not getting steady state error proportional motor controller

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I am designing a [proportional controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_control) for a DC motor. I am expecting to get an error of $$\dfrac{K_p}{1+K_p}$$ but the step response of my closed loop system has practically no steady state error (`< 1.0e-6`).

The $A$ and $B$ matrices of my closed loop system are

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\\ -b_0 k_1 &  a_1 -b_0 k_2 & a_2 - b_0 k_3 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ b_0 k_1 & b_0 k_2 & b_0 k_3 \end{bmatrix} $$

For simulation using [Python Control Systems Library](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.3.post2/control.html)'s `control.forced_response()`, I use

$$ C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

Simulating the system with $ k_p = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

1. Re(Eigenvalues) all < 0 so system is stable.
2. Responses shown in figure below.

[image: plots]

I expect the position to have a steady state value of 0.5 radians since

$$\frac{k_1}{1 + k_1} = \frac{1}{1 + 1} = \frac12$$

Why am I not getting a steady state error in my position response, or if I am, why is it so small?

The process maps voltage to position.

$$ \dfrac{\Theta(s)}{E(s)} = \dfrac{b_0}{a_2s^3 + a_1s^2 + a_0s}$$

Comment: What is your plant precisely? You can of course have perfect reference tracking (no input disturbances) with a stabilizing controller if the plant has an integrator. The TF from voltage to angular position has an integrator for a DC motor.

Comment: I added the TF in the question. I will read in to this phenomenon, I thought there would always be some sort of steady state error.

Comment: The keyword to search for is *Internal Model Principle*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your plant is,

$$P(s) = \frac{b_0}{a_2 s^3 + a_1 s^2 + a_0 s}$$

and your controller is,

$$C(s) = K_p$$

then the TF from the reference $R(s)$ to the error $E(s)$ is,

$$\frac{E(s)}{R(s)} = \frac{1}{1 + P(s) C(s)} = \frac{a_2 s^3 + a_1 s^2 + a_0 s}{a_2 s^3 + a_1 s^2 + a_0 s + K_p}$$

Assuming closed-loop stability, we can see the DC gain of this TF is $0$, implying no error in the steady-state response to a step reference. This principle generalizes in a way that is known as the Internal Model Principle: usually it is used to figure out what poles to put in the controller, but it applies just as well to analysis when the plant has the right poles.